# Confusion in rotation matrix - rotation about $y$ axis

Tags: rotations

The rotation matrix about y axis should look like

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\frac{\pi}{2} & 0 &\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin\frac{\pi}{2} & 0 &\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 &1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-1& 0 &0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Now, I pictured this rotation, and it should look like rotation about y axis, counterclockwise

[image]

I drew $(1,1,1)$ vector in original coordinate system, and in the new coordinate system, the vector should be $(-1,1,1)$
[image]

BUT! the matrix calculation gives otherwise.

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 &1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-1& 0 &0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]
=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
-1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Am I missing something?

---

Okay, it seems like I should rotate vector instead of coordinate system.

Then, How can you explain rotation about z axis?

[image]

The rotation matrix is 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\frac{\pi}{2} &\sin\frac{\pi}{2} & 0\\
-\sin\frac{\pi}{2} &\cos\frac{\pi}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 &0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 &1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

But... calculation is correct.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 &0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 &1\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]
=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

IF you rotate the vector, then in the picture, it should be $(-1,1,1)$

[image]

---

Oh. god.... I think I am looking at the wrong source.

My book tells

[image]

well, clearly, googling gives me

[image]

http://what-when-how.com/the-3-d-global-spatial-data-model/rotation-matrix-derivation-the-3-d-global-spatial-data-model/

I think I solved my case. Thank you all.

Comment: You added $ (1,1,1)$ TO WHAT?

Comment: Sorry. edited the sentence.

Comment: the matrix is transforming the vector in the first space to another vector in the same space...

Comment: How is it "what was previously the x-axis is now NEGATIVE z axis" ? not positive z axis?

Comment: I don't understand why: "I drew (1,1,1) vector in original coordinate system, and in the new coordinate system, the vector should be (−1,1,1) ". In fact, the rotation matrix *maps*  (1,1,1)  to (1,1,-1). The matrix *transform* the vector. It *doesn't* express the old vector in the new basis. I think you are missing two different things

Comment: Initially, you wrote the matrix of a rotation of $\pi/2$ `clockwise`.

Comment: The book containing wrong notation is _J. F. Rosenbaum, Bulk Acoustic Wave Theory and Devices (Artech House_. 
Boston, 1988),

Comment: What did you use for drawing the axes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Emilio Novati Explained very well about the rotation. But I spent some time draw this picture, so I'll post it.

You misunderstood the rotation matrix. You should rotate the vector counterclockwisely, instead of rotate the coordinate system.

[image]

Comment: I edited my question. can you explain to me?

Comment: Well, I solved my case. I think your answer gave me a hint.

Comment: @user65452: Notice that your final matrices A.1, A.2 and A.3 are in fact the $R^{-1}$ mentioned in Emilio Novati's answer. So to perform the rotation of vector, you should use the matrix that switches the signs of $\sin\theta$. Anyway your book is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are confusing [active and passive rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).

Your matrix $R$, applied to a vector $v$, give you a rotated vector $v'=Rv$ that is expressed in the same reference system than $v$ and this is called an **active transformation**.

If you don't change the vector but rotate the axis of the referenc system, than this is called a **passive transformation** and it is represented by the inverse matrix $R^{-1}$, in the sense that the coordinates of the old vector in the new reference systems are $v''=R^{-1}v$.

Comment: I edited my question. why is that rotation about y axis gives wrong answer and rotation about z axis gives right answer?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Anyway, the difference between active and passive rotation is the same for any axis of rotation.

Comment: Oh. well, I was using wrong matrix. see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are viewing the problem backwards. The matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
rotates a vector into a new, rotated frame, according to what you are describing with your images. However, what you are asking is, "What matrix brings me from the rotated frame back to the original frame", which would be the inverse of $A$, i.e.
$$
A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: the rotation of a vector along the Y axis by an angle $\theta$ is
the same rotation of the landmark  OXZ along the Y axis by the
angle $-\theta$ . i think, this is where there is confusion with
the Schema.

Comment: sorry, the comment for the autor user65452, thanks